# No DevTools breakpoints for v3 extension? (apparently import issue)

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have a pretty simple extension.

Manifest:

```
"background": { 
    "service_worker": "background.js",
    "type": "module"
  },
  "minimum_chrome_version": "92",
```

Tools.js:

```
export function ToolsMethod(url) { return ""; }
```

background.js:

```
import "./Tools.js";

function A(info,tab) {
   ToolsMethod(tab.url);
}

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {

  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: "A.id",
    title: "A", 
    contexts:["page"]
  });

const menuItemMap = { A: "A.id" }
const handlerMap = { [menuItemMap.A]:A  }
  
  chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function (info, tab) {
    // !!! breakpoint is here 
    const { menuItemId } = info;
    const handler = handlerMap[menuItemId];
    if (handler) handler(info, tab);
  });
  
});
```

So, breakpoint is not working (devtools never stops there) and, the most important, A is never called when I click context menu: just nothing happens.

If I remove "import", "type" and just copy the code from Tools.js to background.js, it works fine (still no debug tho). Still, not what I'm looking for.

Any suggestions on how to debug/fix?

UPD: here's the reproducible zip: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ElQ857W_opTwXJ7jxMHZuylaoNFEbWTh/view?usp=sharing
Steps to repro:

1. Install the extension
2. Go to [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07FC2RN6G?ref=myi_title_dp](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FC2RN6G) (just a random product)
3. Expected result: context menu "Clan URL" updates current page URL to "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07FC2RN6G" (cleans up the mess in the right side)
4. Current result: nothing happens after the click on the context menu. No stops at the breakpoints as well

Comment: How are you doing the export in Tools.js?

Comment: Okay, that was an extremely valid point. Because I've did not export it at all :) 
However, after I add `export` to the method ToolsMethod(), I've started to get error "ToolsMethod() is not defined". Wut?
(I've updated the question)

Comment: Add a minimum reproducible example of Tools.js

Comment: Yep, okay, working on it. Will be in 5 minutes. Thanks. @ManuelMB

Comment: You're calling `chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener()` inside the `chrome.runtime.onInstalled` listener. If you install the extension and then restart Chrome, the `chrome.contextMenus.onClicked` listener will be gone.

Comment: In your example code, `handler` will always be `undefined`. Because `handlerMap` is `{ "A.id": A }`, but `info.menuItemId` is `"A"`.

Comment: @ThomasMueller Right, thanks! Fixed. Just a sampling typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are doing the import is wrong, the following code works ok:

- background.js

  ```
  import { sayBye, ToolsMethod } from './Tools.js';

  chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {

  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: "A",
    title: "A", 
    contexts:["page"]
  });

  chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function (info, tab) {
        console.log(sayBye())
        console.log(ToolsMethod('https://stackoverflow.com'))
  });
  ```

  });
- Tools.js

  ```
  export const ToolsMethod = (url) => { return 'Hello World'; }

  export function sayBye() {
     return 'Bye'; 
  }
  ```

A more convenient way of exporting all the items you want to export is to use a single export statement at the end of your module file,
followed by a comma-separated list of the features you want to export wrapped in curly braces.

```
export {ToolsMethod, sayBye };
```

[Modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)

[Manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/contextMenus/)
Also You must declare the "contextMenus" permission in your extension's manifest to use the API. Also, you should specify a 16x16-pixel icon for display next to your menu item.

```
   {
    "name": "My extension",
    ...
    "permissions": [
        "contextMenus"
    ],
    "icons": {
        "16": "icon-bitty.png",
        "48": "icon-small.png",
        "128": "icon-large.png"
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: Riiight, so the issue is with import syntax. Thanks!
Manifest issues are due to the repro-sample cut, but thank you noted that anyways.

Comment: Also, it seems breakpoints works fine (sometimes), but in overall its so much glitchy and unstable comparing the v2...

Comment: what are the other gitchyness?